# Python - plt.subplot() with plot created in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I create the following plots within a for loop:

```
cat_var={}
categories=['symboling','fuel-type','make']

for x in categories:
    cat_var[x]=df[x].unique()

for key in cat_var.keys():
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    for value in cat_var[key]:
        subset= df[df[key] == value]
        sns.distplot(subset['price'], hist = False, kde = True,kde_kws = {'linewidth': 3},label = value) 
    plt.legend(prop={'size': 16}, title = key)
    plt.title('Price distribution per %s level'% key)
    plt.xlabel('Price')
    plt.ylabel('Density')
    plt.show()
```

It is working, but I would like to plot them so they appear all on the same row, whereas now I have them all on the same column. I was thinking about using something like:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3,figsize=(20,20))
```

but this does not produce the desired output wherever I put this last line of code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have three plots on the same figure, then you need to use subplots and specify where each plot goes

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3,figsize=(20,20))
for idx, key in enumerate(cat_var):       
    for value in cat_var[key]:
        subset= df[df[key] == value]
        sns.distplot(subset['price'], hist = False, ax= ax[idx], kde = True,kde_kws = {'linewidth': 3},label = value)  
plt.show()
```

With the following output:

[image]

Comment: it's really hard to provide a working solution without your data,  but it is a good starting point :)

Comment: Here is where the data can be found: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data you are right I should have included that in my question. The solution is not really working yet, but that is definitely a good start.

Comment: where are the headers? your data is non labeled hence the column syntax you're using can't be used on the raw data

Comment: I just tried my code with dummy column names and it worked

Comment: Thanks, this only works when I do not use plt.legend, plt.title, plt.xlabel and plt.ylabel. Not sure why.

Comment: that's because plt is used when you're doing a simple plot. When you're doing subplots you need to use ax[idx].set_title('your title')